# Representing an ISW wavefunction graphically

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

I'm trying to decode this diagram given to us for an assignment.

[image]

The description of the diagram is 'Consider a particle of mass m confined to a 1-dimensional square well, given graphically by
the above wavefunction at time t = 0'.

So I'm guessing that it's showing the boundary conditions for the wavefunction at time t=0? i.e.

$$\psi\bigg(\frac{L}{3}\bigg) = \psi\bigg(\frac{2L}{3}\bigg) = B$$

Or more generally, is it implying that the wavefunction is constant for that region at time t=0 ? i.e.

$$\psi(x) = B \text{ for } \frac{L}{3} \leq x \leq \frac{2L}{3}$$

Comment: Hint: B is just the height of potential for the mentioned range. Don't take it as a value of the wavefunction of the particle. It can be interpreted as a possibility of the particle tunneling through the barrier between two sides. Since 0<B<Infinity, the wavefunction won't vanish necessarily in that range.

Comment: My immediate reaction to this is that the black line is showing you $\Psi(x,0)$ and you're supposed to calculate it's evolution (which you'd do by Fourier expanding it). Bill obviously thinks the black line shows you the potential i.e. your well has a finite barrier in the middle. I don't see how we can be sure of the interpretation without asking whoever set the problem.

Comment: I'd agree with John, it rather looks like this. But jamesmartini should tell, if this interpretation is too complicated to be meant. Do you know what the eigenstates of such a potential are, and how mixed-energy-states evolve?

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 regions of constant potential:
$$V(x<0)=V(x>L)\to \infty$$
$$V\left(0<x<\frac{L}{3}\right)=V\left(\frac{2L}{3}<x<L\right)=0$$
$$V\left(\frac{L}{3}<x<\frac{2L}{3}\right)=B$$

After determining the basic form of the wave function in each region, you have to match the wave functions from adjoining regions at each transition point $\left(0,\frac{L}{3},\frac{2L}{3},L\right)$, and match the slopes at each finite transition $\left(\frac{L}{3},\frac{2L}{3}\right)$.

$B$ is a value of the potential, not the value of the wave function.

Of course, then you have to normalize the function.  If you've solved a step function or rectangular barrier, this should be straight forward.

The specification of $t=0$ is simply to allow you to find the energy eigenstates and eigenvalues before having to build a time dependent wave function.  Also, the normalization factor will be time independent because the potential is real.